# c program to divide a number and show mod of a number won't work

Tags: c, integer, modulus, integer-division

Hi I made a program which integer divides a number by 50 and shows the mod of that number also but the compiler tells me that "value requires left operand of assignment" for"/" I'm not sure what to do. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    int i;
    int m;

    printf("enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    num / 50 = i;
    num % 50 = m;

    printf("the division is: %d\n", i);
    printf("the remainder is: %d", m);
```

return(0);
}

Comment: your assignment statement is backwards

Comment: You should probably get a good beginner C book and go through it.

Comment: lol, ^ even if that sounds a little mean, they do help a lot

Comment: I just started a course at uni just a few queries here and there but thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
num / 50 = i;  
num % 50 = m;
```

Is seriously illegal in C. You have to do this:

```
i = num / 50;
m = num % 50;
```

Why? Because the equals sign in C doesn't work the way it does in math. In math, an equals sign establishes that two expressions are *already* equal. It tells you something new about them, but doesn't change them.

In C, it's expressly used to change a variable, something you can't really do in traditional math notation. It copies the value on the right into the variable address on the left. That's why some people call it "gets" instead of "equals," as in "i gets num / 50." It makes sense when you read it that way.

Answer (score 4):

your assignment statement is backwards

use:

```
i = num / 50;
m = num % 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

**replace**  `num / 50 = i;` and  `num % 50 = m;` with `i = num / 50;` and `m = num % 50;`

Answer (score 0):

In C , while using assignment operator L.H.S should be L-value not r-value(i.e. it should have address associated with it ) hence use
i = num / 50;
m = num % 50;